# Json not passing date in correct formate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
app.controller('CustomerCareController', ['$scope','$filter',   'CustomerCareService','CustomerService',
    function ($scope, $filter, customerCarService, customerService) { 
$scope.seletedCustomerCarePreviousIdChanged = function () {           

           var serverObject = {
               CustomerCareId: $scope.selectedCustomerCarePreviousId
           }

           var successcallBackCarePreviousFeedbackInfo = function (data) {

               $scope.CustomerCarePreviousFeedBack = data;


           }
           customerCarService.getCustomerCarePreviousFeedBackDetail(serverObject, successcallBackCarePreviousFeedbackInfo);
     }])
```

This is service.js code.

```
    var getCustomerCarePreviousFeedBackDetail = function (serverObject,         successCallbackPreviousFeedBack) {
              resource.CustomerCare.getCustomerCarePreviousFeedBackDetail(serverObject).$promi      se.then(function (response) {
            successCallbackPreviousFeedBack(response);
                });
```

This is Resource.js

```
            'getCustomerCarePreviousFeedBackDetail': { method: 'POST', isArray:true, url: '/CustomerCare/GetCutomerCarePreviousFeedBackDetail' },
```

This is MVC Controller

```
public ActionResult GetCutomerCarePreviousFeedBackDetail(string customerCareId)
        {

        List<CustomerCareFeedBackDTO> myList;
        BOCustomerCare customer=new BOCustomerCare();
        myList = customer.GetCustomerCarePreviousFeedBack(customerCareId);
        return Json(myList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is my Businees Operation Layer..

```
 public List<CustomerCareFeedBackDTO> GetCustomerCarePreviousFeedBack(string customerCareId)
    {
        try
        {
            ICustomerCareModule customerCareModule = IOContainer.Resolve<ICustomerCareModule>();
            return  customerCareModule.GetCustomerCarePreviousFeedBackDetail(customerCareId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("faild to get info");

        }
        }
```

This is my Module Code

```
 public List<CustomerCareFeedBackDTO> GetCustomerCarePreviousFeedBackDetail(string customerCareId)
    {
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
        ICustomerCareRepository customerCareRepository = unitOfWork.CustomerCareRepository;

        return Mapper.Map<List<CustomerCareFeedBack>, List<CustomerCareFeedBackDTO>>
            (customerCareRepository.GetCustomerCarePreviouFeedBack(customerCareId));
        }
```

This my Repository Code.

```
  public List<CustomerCareFeedBack> GetCustomerCarePreviouFeedBack(string customerCareId)
    {
        return _dbContext.CustomerCareFeedBacks.Where(c => c.CustomerCareId == customerCareId).Select(c => c).ToList();

        }
```

This is HTML

```
 <tbody>
 <tr data-ng-repeat="o in CustomerCarePreviousFeedBack">
 <td>{{o.Date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
 <td>{{o.FeedBackDetail}}</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Other information m getting thorough this mathod are accurate but date is not in correct formate.
Json is not passing date in correct formate the format of date json passing is /Date(1441959099210)/

Comment: Can we have more details about your Json ? or a JsFiddle/Codepen

Comment: var getCustomerCarePreviousFeedBackDetail = function (serverObject, successCallbackPreviousFeedBack) {
            resource.CustomerCare.getCustomerCarePreviousFeedBackDetail(serverObject).$promise.then(function (response) {
                successCallbackPreviousFeedBack(response);
            });
        };     this is my service.js file code

Comment: you might want to add more tags, because this is more then just AngularJS

Comment: <td>{{o.Date.substr(6,13) | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
                                        <td>{{o.FeedBackDetail}}</td>